Young girl with scars on face
I believe it features Susan Ward.
The story is that of a young girl with scars or burns on her face. She meets a young lad. He takes interest and sets her up for a robbery, but she's caught and goes to prison.
She makes a friend while in there. She catches the eye of a doctor who helps to make her beautiful. Some years later, she sets up business with her prison friend.
She meets the man who set her up at the beginning, but he doesn't recognize her. She soon realizes that her sister is with the man. The sister finds out who they are and they both get their revenge on him  

This is the exact plot of A Face To Die For (AKA The Face) from 1996: A scarred woman falls in love with a guy named Alec who convinces her to steal money from her employer. She's caught and sent to prison, where she befriends her cellmate (Robin Givens), attracts a surgeon who fixes her face and learns that Alec is now with her sister. When she gets out, she opens up a business with her former cellmate and decides to take revenge on Alec.
But the heroine is played by Yasmine Bleeth (who I guess bears a passing resemblance to Susan Ward). I checked if Ward played in another film adaptation (it's based on a book) but found nothing.

